# surefire plugin > version 2.19 and junit suites

Tags: java, junit, maven-surefire-plugin, junit5

I'm struggling to get maven-surefire-plugin version 2.22.0 to run junit test suites.

Suites are defined by junit5 annotations

```
@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
@SelectClasses({
        SetupTest.class,
        SessionTest.class,
})
public class APITests {
}
```

Or by junit4

```
@RunWith(ProgressSuite.class)
@SuiteClasses({
        CountryTest.class,
        PaymentTypeTest.class,
})
public class APITests  {
}
```

Both cases result in surefire finding no tests and throwing a error

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.0:test
>   (default-test) on project integrationTests: No tests were executed!

If I simply run one the the test classes directly, that works fine.
Before this attempted update to surefire-plugin 2.22, the older version 2.19.1 could run these 'suites' just fine.

Has anybody got some supporting ideas at how I can continue to use my suites?

Relevant portions of POM below.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>8</source>
                <target>8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>SureFireParseReportAndStore</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>surefireReporting.SureFireParseReportAndStore</mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                    <nonFilteredFileExtension>exe</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>repo.jenkins-ci.org</id>
        <url>http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.exparity</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-date</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.surefire/surefire-report-parser -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
        <artifactId>surefire-report-parser</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.1</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

Comment: Could you please post your `JUnit 5` dependencies and `maven-surefire-plugin` configuration from your `pom.xml` ? I think this might be an error because of incopatible versions of dependencies.

Comment: I've edited original question to include pom details